# Extract strings from DataFrame, join with previous column and merge with another DataFrame

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have two csv files/Pandas Dataframes organized like

```
Sheet ID         Issue                                             Obs
P012CR0409F1-1,  P012CR0409F1-1-04, P012CR0409F1-1-05 crop again,
P012CR0427F1-1,  Missing image 08                               ,
P012V006-0018 ,  Missing images 01, 04, 05, 09                  ,
```

and

```
Image ID           Value1     Value2
P012CR0427F1-1-01  0.85839    0.76264
```

I need to end up with a single dataframe that is essentially the second one with two additional boolean columns: `crop again` and `missing`.

So for the first new column the plan is to use `(?P<crop>[\w-]+)(?=(?:\s*,\s*[\w-]+)*\s+crop again)` to isolate the image codes and for the second `(?!Missing? images?) (?P<missing>\d{2})` to isolate the missing indexes.

I'm struggling with how to 1. Join the missing indexes with their sheet ID to get the missing images codes' and 2. Join all this in the last dataframe. I'm not terrible at 2D Pandas but the `extractall` function returns a MultiIndex object that I can't really understand how to operate.

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing was:

```
df = pd.read_csv("./First.csv", names=["id", "issue", "obs"])
df["crop"] = df["issue"].str.findall(
    r"(?P<crop>[\w-]+)(?=(?:\s*,\s*[\w-]+)*\s+crop again)"
)
df["missing"] = df["issue"].str.findall(
    r"(?!Missing images?) (?P<missing>\d{2})"
)
df = df.explode("crop")
df = df.explode("missing")
df["missing"] = df["id"] + "-" + df["missing"]
crop = df["crop"].dropna()
missing = df["missing"].dropna()
```

from there I used both as Series but it would be straightforward to check for them in Second.csv and add the boolean columns.